# Several conditions with IF

Tags: excel, formula, finance

i have a data set in Excel where in the 1st column there is and ID with 12 characters in which i must change from 1 to -1 if the first 6 characters from left to right has several conditions.

I have tried the following, but i cant get it work with out using VBA

```
=IFT((LEF([@Cuenta],6)=AND("503-01","503-02","503-50","503-60")),-1,A847)
```

I would like to make it as short as possible cause the person that works with the sheet gets confused with long formulas

Comment: I think there is typo in your formula: `IFT((LEF(...` should be `IF((LEFT(...`

Comment: Hi, thanks it was a typo when i copy the formula but it doesnt work without the typo

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to fix the typo, otherwise people will focus on that.

Comment: `=IF(OR(LEFT([@Cuenta],6)={"503-01","503-02","503-50","503-60"}),-1,A847)`

Comment: Hi Scott now we have a new problem the formula works but i think it is to long =IF(F6="","",IF(LEFT(F6,1)="4",-1,IF(OR(LEFT(F6,6)={"503-01","503-02","503-50","503-60"}),-1,IF(LEFT(F3011,6)="404-70",1,1))*SI.ERROR(N(I6<>43),1))).